# How to add a download hyperlink for downloading attachments from website in odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I want to add a hyperlink in the website module in odoo using which I can download the attachments which consists of information of the product which was created.Please help with with this problem .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer this question. Anyway it might be helpful to some one. I have googled more, since i didn't get any write solution.

**Step 1:**
Create hyperlink for download button. In that button you need to pass

1. model name
2. field
3. id
4. filename (optional)

For an example your link should be like this

```
<a t-attf-href="/web/binary/download_document?model=product.brand.files&amp;field=file&amp;id={{ file.id }}&amp;file_name={{ file.file_name }}">
```

**Step 2:**

Create controller for above link. Ex

```
class Binary(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/web/binary/download_document', type='http', auth="public")
    @serialize_exception
    def download_document(self,model,field,id,file_name=None, **kw):
        """ Download link for files stored as binary fields.
        :param str model: name of the model to fetch the binary from
        :param str field: binary field
        :param str id: id of the record from which to fetch the binary
        :param str filename: field holding the file's name, if any
        :returns: :class:`werkzeug.wrappers.Response`
        """
        Model = request.env[model].sudo().search([('id', '=', int(id))])
        filecontent = base64.b64decode(Model.file or '')
        headers = werkzeug.datastructures.Headers()
        if not filecontent:
            return request.not_found()
        else:
            if not file_name:
                filename = '%s_%s' % (model.replace('.', '_'), id)
                headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
                return request.make_response(filecontent,headers)
            else:
                headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
                return request.make_response(filecontent,headers)
```

It will work. Above code for Odoo 10. You can do the same for below versions also. I have got refer from [this link](http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/odoo-technical-notes-59/post/how-to-download-any-file-on-button-click-244)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'url': '/web/content/%s/%s' % (attachment_id.id, shortname),
    'target': 'self',
    'nodestroy': False,
}
```

In short you just have to have a link that goes to `/web/content/ir_attachment_id/the_name_you_want_the_file_to_have`.

This works on Odoo V10 too.

Answer (score 0):

this is work from odoo 10 you must try

```
<a t-attf-href="/web/content?model=website.support.ticket.message&amp;field=attachment&amp;id={{chat.id}}&amp;filename={{chat.attachment_filename}}&amp;download=true">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a form you could do this entirely in the view. First add a record entry somewhere in the xml file:

```
<record id="module_name.http_link" model="ir.actions.act_url">
  <field name="name">Button Name</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_url</field>
  <field name="target">new</field>
  <field name="url">https://your-http-link</field>
</record>
```

And then in the form:

```
<button type="action" name="%(http_link)d" string="Name" class="oe_highlight"/>
```